# high $p_T$ and low $p_T$ b-jet energy correction factor

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider

For b-jets, to get the true transverse momentum using the reconstructed $p_T$, we use a correction factor $p_{T}^{gen}/p_{T}^{reco}$ obtained using MC. Now suppose I make a plot of $p_{T}^{gen}/p_{T}^{reco}$. for low $p_T$ b-jet, do I expect the resolution of this plot to be higher than the plot for high $p_T$ b-jets? What I feel is that the resolution of the plot of energy correction factor for low $p_T$ would be higher than the plot for high $p_T$ b-jets because to what I know is that high $p_T$ particles are well reconstructed than low $p_T$ particles in LHC. But could someone please throw more light to this question, or if you have any comments to add as to why high $p_T$ b-jets are well reconstructed as compared to low $p_T$ particles...

Comment: Higher pT tend to leave less "debris" around them due to their interaction with the detector material. But why do you think that less well-reconstructed particles are expected to have higher resolution on their correction factor? Can you elaborate, or link to a plot?